# R custom function which takes an integer i, then returns an integer-appended variable name

Tags: r

How do I create a custom function which takes an integer input, and uses that integer input as a parameter to another function inside it, and returns a variable which appends the integer to its name?

For example:

```
f <- function(i) {
  var_i<-another.Function(parameter="ni")
  }
```

This should return the variable `var_1` if I pass `i=1`.

My goal is to implement parallel processing using this function which I would pass a range of integers for processes, i.e `mclapply(1:13,f)`

I initially used `eval(parse=text...`, however I have read that is is not the recommended method.

Comment: Add `names(var_i) <- paste0("var_",i)`  and `return(var_i)` within your function

Answer (score 0):

A quick way that you could do it if you want to pass this for a range of integers is using *assign* (base) which creates variables and *paste* (base),

```
for (i in 1:10){  #or whatever range you want to use

#assign(name of var, the value of var (here 2i, but whatever function you need to pass))
assign(paste("var", i, sep = "_"), i*2) }
```

This does not need to a be function as it exports automatically variables to your environment, so if you use it inside the function, you will need to return it to put it to global environment.